# Has something changed with how the Android Marketplace processes the Manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

We are seeing some strange behavior with how the Market processes our Manifest file.  This weekend we noticed that our list of available devices dropped from 590 to 196.  If I then take a look at the Device List itself I now have devices that can no longer Enable or Disable manually as they are an "unsupported device due to your manifest settings".

Has anyone else noticed this behavior recently?  Has there been any new Filter Parameters added?

The Required device features shown are:

```
android.hardware.location.network
android.hardware.microphone
android.hardware.location
android.hardware.touchscreen
android.hardware.screen.portrait
```

Our Manifest has the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
...
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
```